# Google Sheets double click fill down not working

Tags: google-sheets

If I select a cell and then double-click on the blue dot at the bottom-right of the cell, the fill-down function does not work, nothing happens.

Sometimes it does work, in other cases/columns.

The cells below are empty, but that shouldn't matter.

There is no filter applied to the sheet.

If I select two cells and try the same thing, it doesn't work.

Help appreciated.

([also posted in the Google Sheets support forum](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/226343177))

Comment: This question is an exact copy of [Google Sheets double click fill down not working](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/226343177) that has an answer. See [Be Forthright When Cross Posting To Other Sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824).

Comment: @doubleunary That doesn't matter much. The answer here is better. This better answer wouldn't have existed without crossposting

Comment: Cross-posting is acceptable as long as the poster is [forthright](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/141824/1272824) about it.

Answer (score 1):

The solution I used was to select the first cell, scroll down to the last cell, hold down shift, select the last cell, and then used CMD+D (Mac) / CTRL + D (Windows) to fill down into the selection.

There is a [keyboard shortcuts page here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/181110)

([Based on the original answer here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/226343177?hl=en&msgid=226346383))

Comment: This is the correct answer